# Is it possible to make minecarts kill someone if it comes in contact with a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I thought of a cool new minigame, which involves instant-death if you come into contact with a Minecart.

I'd like to put this together in Vanilla (unmodded) Minecraft, so can a Minecart kill players if it touches them, without mods? (Not explode)

Comment: Have you tried anything? I would suggest checking for a way to detect player/minecart collision, once you know a player has been hit by one you can kill them in a range of ways, depending on what you're after (e.g. add a status effect, teleport them high into the sky or just plain kill them, whatever works for your game)

Comment: Have you made any attempt to make this yourself?  Arqade works much better when you attempt to solve your problem before asking here.  Showing us that effort helps us provide you a better answer, focusing specifically on where you're stuck.  We get a better question, you get a better answer.  Everybody wins!

Answer (score 6):

Run this on a clock:

```
/execute @e[type=MinecartRideable] ~ ~ ~ kill @p[r=1]
```

Comment: And technically, this will still kill players riding minecarts, but I can't think of a good way to both implement this *and* prevent that potentially undesired behavior

Comment: It should be possible to set up a scoreboard checking for `{Riding:{MinecartRideable}}` to prevent killing riders.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute at @e[type=minecart] run kill @p[distance=..1]`